# как оптимизировать in?

Tags: python, оптимизация

Как оптимизировать эту часть кода?

```
for block in blocks:
        if d:
            block[1][0] -= 4
            upd.append([block[1][0], block[1][1]+math.sin(j/57.2958)*40, 32, 32])
        if a:
            block[1][0] += 4
            upd.append([block[1][0], block[1][1]+math.sin(j/57.2958)*40, 32, 32])
        if block[1][0] > 1280:
            block[1][0] -= 1312
        if block[1][0] < -32:
            block[1][0] += 1312
        #больше всего производительности сжирает часть кода от сюда:
        if block[0][0] == grass and([[grass, grass1, grass2, grass3], [block[1][0], block[1][1]-32]] in blocks or [[dirt, dirt1, dirt2, dirt3], [block[1][0], block[1][1]-32]] in blocks):
            block[0] = [dirt, dirt1, dirt2, dirt3]
        if block[0][0] == dirt and not ([[grass, grass1, grass2, grass3], [block[1][0], block[1][1]-32]] in blocks or [[dirt, dirt1, dirt2, dirt3], [block[1][0], block[1][1]-32]] in blocks):
            block[0] = [grass, grass1, grass2, grass3]
        #до сюда
```

Я изучил и понял: именно проблема в in.
Как оптимизировать это?

Comment: Если просто "в лоб", то как минимум не вычислять одно и то же выражение `([[grass, grass1, grass2, grass3], [block[1][0], block[1][1]-32]] in blocks or [[dirt, dirt1, dirt2, dirt3], [block[1][0], block[1][1]-32]] in blocks)` два раза.

Comment: я попробовал, ничего не изменилось, и появился баг.

Comment: а) что должно было измениться? б) если появился баг, значит неправильно пробовал.

Comment: уменьшится потребление возможностей ЦП. Сейчас программа сжирает 36 процентов ЦП. А баг в том что все блоки грязи становятся блоками травы.

Comment: Значит не так переписал `if`ы.

Comment: Вы ещё и на ходу меняете то, по чему итерируетесь? Как-то это всё странно выглядит. Что вы вообще делаете, в чём суть?

Comment: Я решил баг. Он был из-за того, что рассчеты `([[grass, grass1, grass2, grass3], [block[1][0], block[1][1]-32]] in blocks or [[dirt, dirt1, dirt2, dirt3], [block[1][0], block[1][1]-32]] in blocks)` я делал да вычисления позиции блока. Но все еще 36 процентов потребление.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я делаю игру вроде майнкрафт, но в 2D. Нашлась проблема с оптимизацией и я не знаю как ее решить.

Comment: Главное, что нужно сделать - изменить структуру данных, чтобы она позволяла делать операции, которые делаются часто, (в данном случае поиск) быстро. Линейный поиск, как сделано сейчас, не будет хорошо работать для большого списка blocks. Подсказать, как именно изменить - затруднительно. Неясно по каким критериям вы ищете сейчас, текущая структура данных из этого куска кода очень туманная.

Comment: Я не ищу объект, мне надо узнать есть ли он  списки или нет.

Comment: По терминологии спорить не буду - называйте эту операцию как хотите. Суть написанного мною это никак не меняет.

Comment: Спасибо. Я сделал поиск по деревьям разделив блоки на 2 группы: земля и трава. В результате потребление ЦП снизилось с 36 до 24 процентов. планирую еще разделить по деревьям.